# Scaling a Titan index backed by Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, titan

I am interested in using Titan as a database. I would like to use Elasticsearch as the indexing backend. One concern I have is that Elasticsearch does not support index scaling; it is impossible to add shards to an already established index. Because of this restriction, scaling an index in Elasticsearch involves creating an entirely new index with more shards and copying over the data from the old index. It is also not possible to rename an index in Elasticsearch (i.e. you cannot "flip" the new index once it has all the old data).

What is the proper solution to scaling an index in Titan given these constraints? It seems lame to have to bounce the cluster if you want to scale the index.

Comment: I have already told you that to scale an index you'll need to add a node.

Comment: Yes, but adding nodes only benefits performance if there is an existing node with two or more shards. If this limit has already been reached, then a new index must be created and the Titan cluster must be bounced to learn about the new index. I am trying to find a way to avoid that. Taking down the cluster to scale does not meet the SLA I need to meet.

Comment: I have a feeling the solution will involve aliases: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html

Comment: You don't need to take down the cluster when you add nodes. You were trying to add shards and that's something completely different. You can also use aliasing as a solution for you add new indices.

Comment: What I am saying is that adding nodes is not a horizontally scalable solution because you're bound by the number of shards that were chosen when the index was created. Also, it is the Titan cluster that must come down because it requires the index name when it starts up.

Comment: Why are you fixating on the number of shards? as if it's the only scalabitility with elasticsearch...

Comment: Because I'm designing a horizontally scalable solution. It is a hard requirement. If the shard number is fixed, then the solution is not horizontally scalable. It is as simple as that.

Comment: The number of primary shards is fixed at the moment an index is created. Effectively, that number defines the maximum amount of data that can be stored in the index. (The actual number depends on your data, your hardware and your use case.) However, read requests—searches or document retrieval—can be handled by a primary or a replica shard, so the more copies of data that you have, the more search throughput you can handle.

Comment: @Max what if you create another index when the first one reached its "limits", if you don't want to re-index the data? When searching you search an alias that contains all indices, when indexing you index in an alias that points to the "current" index.

Comment: IIRC, you cannot write through an alias.

Comment: @Max you can index in an alias if it points to a single index ;-). If it points to more than one index, it's an error.

Comment: I see. I don't think that Titan supports this. It also doesn't fully solve the problem because eventually you will want to update documents and the old index will contain out-of-date information.

Comment: Then you need to re-index when you want to increase the number of primary shards. There's no way out of this. But, it is a rather unusual use case for Elasticsearch to have one large index that grows without limits. And, yes, there is limit related to how much a shard can hold. And this depends on many variables.